# How should I validate the complete string format using regex in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to validate the below string format:

```
'(:abc-xyz :abd-xyz-abx :v2-abc)'
```

I have tried creating a regex as :

`const regex = RegExp('^[(][:][a-z|0-9|-]+(?: [:][a-z|0-9|-]+)*[)]$');`

It is working for me for most of the cases but failing to validate when the string is :

string = '(:abc--xyz- :abc-xyz-abx- :v2-abc-)'

How should I validate the string so that '-' is allowed in between the word but not at the end of each word?

my requirement is :

```
string='(:abc-xyz :abd-xyz-abx :v2-abc)' -> Correct (only valid format others are incorrect).

example :
string='(:abc--xyz :abd-xyz-abx :v2--abc)' -> Incorrect
string='(:abc-xyz :abd-xyz-abx :v2-abc-)' -> Incorrect
string='(:abc-xyz:abd-xyz-abx :v2-abc-)' -> Incorrect
```

https://regex101.com/r/kJwWPt/1

Comment: I added you a regex101 link - please specify WHY the others are invalid

Comment: You don't have to add character class for each character: like this `[(][:]`. You can omit the `[]`. But you'd have to escape the metacharacters like `(` with a ``\``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use take the `-` out of the character class, and use optionally repeating groups where you prefix the  `:` and `-`

Also the `|` in the character class will match the pipe literally, so you can omit that if you don't want to match it.

```
^\(:[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*(?: :[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*)*\)$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `\(:` Match `(:`
- `[a-z0-9]+` Match 1+ times any of `a-z0-9`
- `(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*` Optionally repeat `-` and 1+ times any of `a-z0-9`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `:[a-z0-9]+`
  - `(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*` Optionally repeat `-` and 1+ times any of `a-z0-9`
- `)*` Close non capture group and repeat 0+ times
- `\)` Match `)`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JW1APH/1)

```js
let pattern = /^\(:[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*(?: :[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*)*\)$/;
[
  "(:abc-xyz :abd-xyz-abx :v2-abc)",
  "(:abc--xyz- :abc-xyz-abx- :v2-abc-)",
  "(:abc--xyz :abd-xyz-abx :v2--abc)",
  "(:abc-xyz :abd-xyz-abx :v2-abc-)",
  "(:abc-xyz:abd-xyz-abx :v2-abc-)",
].forEach(s => console.log(`${s} ==> ${pattern.test(s)}`));
```